# Emoji unicodes aren't displayed correctly in Javascript(vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, emoji, unicode-escapes

I am trying to display emojis inside my Vue.JS app, using this plugin [vue-twemoji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-twemoji)

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<input type="text" v-model="text" />
<div v-html="parseEmoji"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
props: {
    message: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  }
  data(){
    return {
      text: 'I \u2764\uFE0F emoji! ',
    }
},
computed:{
  parseEmoji: function () {
    let self = this
    return twemoji.parse(this.text)
  }
}
})
```

CSS

```
.emoji{
  width: 16px;
}
```

It works fine and is displayed as such "I ❤️ emoji!", but if the value of "text" variable isn't specifically written in the js file and was received as a property/input to the component, the emoji's remain as Unicode like this

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<input type="text" v-model="message" />
<div v-html="message"></div>
</div>
```

So for two strings, even when I try to log them to the console using the following

```
console.log('I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!')
console.log(this.message)
```

the first one would give "I ❤️ emoji!" and the second one would still give me "I \u2764\uFE0F emoji!". Even though this. message has the exact same string.